# Include HTML form and form processor in Wordpress

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, include, processor

I'm not at all familiar with Wordpress so please bear with me...I have a site on Wordpress. On the homepage is where I want to include an HTML form which would post to a it's own PHP processor. The form and the form processor are both separate PHP files. I would like to know how I can include the form in a specific DIV on my homepage. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried just modifying whatever Page you have set as the homepage? Or adding a text widget? Or modifying the template file?

Comment: You do that with a plugin you write your own. Writing plugins is outlined in codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin - Alternatively you can also drop code into your theme, but it is a similar concept, so learning how plugins work is not useless.

Comment: @hakra Having no knowledge in WordPress and hitting the ground running directly into plug-in design will most likely confuse him more.

Comment: You never know. I would not say so from my POV, but actually this can be true. So some feedback from OP would not be bad.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the folder `wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/` for the files `home.php` or `index.php`.

If you want the form in the main content area that's where you need to put it (use an `include` to your PHP file).

If you want it in the sidebar there's a `sidebar.php` file you can check out.

If you change the theme twentyeleven be sure to rename the folder and open the `style.css` file and change the name in the css comments too. After that you can enter the wp-admin area and select the *new* theme from the appearance panel. You should do this so that any WordPress updates won't overwrite the files you change.